# Browsersync css injection wont work, only reloading works?

Tags: javascript, build, npm, gulp, browser-sync

I'm on windows, basically, browsersync is suppose to detect and inject css files into the browser when any of the css files changes.

Here is the gulp file...

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({proxy: "localhost:3000"});
    gulp.watch("public/stylesheets/**/*", ['css']);
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
     return gulp.src("public/stylesheets/**/*").pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

in index.html i see both css file is being loaded, script tag by browsersync gets added.

But it simply doesn't work. It worked for 1 day, then it never did.

Comment: Try `*.css` instead of `*`.

Comment: have done that, i've tried direct path as well.

Comment: i think i found problem, even though im putting `link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')`, i think expressjs is automatically embedding the whole css file, any idea how to prevent that.

Comment: found problem, it was prefixfreejs converting link tags into style tags, thus breaking the browsersyn which updates link tags and not style tags.